# Cycle 2 Prev and Next

Tags: html, css, slideshow, cycle2

Good evening, I'm using cycle2 with the prev and next function, but I cannot centre the prev and next function under the images.
I've looked around and I know its going to be something stupid, but I just cannot see it.
Very frustrating.
Thanks
Gary

```js
<script src="../../respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.center.js"></script>
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* Simple fluid media
   Note: Fluid media requires that you remove the media's height and width attributes from the HTML
   http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluid-images/ 
*/
img, object, embed, video {
 max-width: 100%;
}

/* IE 6 does not support max-width so default to width 100% */
.ie6 img {
 width:100%;
}

/*
 Dreamweaver Fluid Grid Properties
 ----------------------------------
 dw-num-cols-mobile:  4;
 dw-num-cols-tablet:  8;
 dw-num-cols-desktop: 12;
 dw-gutter-percentage: 25;
 
 Inspiration from "Responsive Web Design" by Ethan Marcotte 
 http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design
 
 and Golden Grid System by Joni Korpi
 http://goldengridsystem.com/
*/

.fluid {
 clear: both;
 margin-left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 display: block;
}

.fluidList {
    list-style:none;
    list-style-image:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;        
}

/* Mobile Layout: 480px and below. */
  
.gridContainer {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: 86.45%;
 padding-left: 2.275%;
 padding-right: 2.275%;
 clear: none;
 float: none;
}
#div1 {
}
.gallery {
}
.zeroMargin_mobile {
margin-left: 0;
}
.hide_mobile {
display: none;
}

/* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {

.gridContainer {
 width: 90.675%;
 padding-left: 1.1625%;
 padding-right: 1.1625%;
 clear: none;
 float: none;
 margin-left: auto;
}
#div1 {
}
.gallery {
}
.hide_tablet {
display: none;
}
.zeroMargin_tablet {
margin-left: 0;
}
}

/* Desktop Layout: 769px to a max of 1232px.  Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout and Tablet Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {

.gridContainer {
 width: 88.5%;
 max-width: 1232px;
 padding-left: 0.75%;
 padding-right: 0.75%;
 margin: auto;
 clear: none;
 float: none;
 margin-left: auto;
}
#div1 {
}
.gallery {
}
.zeroMargin_desktop {
margin-left: 0;
}
.hide_desktop {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div id="div1" class="fluid"></div>
        <div class="fluid gallery">
        <br />
<br />
<div class="cycle-slideshow"
 data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz"
    data-cycle-timeout="0"
    data-cycle-prev="#prev"
    data-cycle-next="#next"
    data-cycle-center-horz=true
    data-cycle-center-vert=true
>
<img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p2.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p3.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p4.jpg">
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="center">
    <span style="text-align: center; text-decoration: none; font:open-sans; font-size:12px; color:#000000;">
    <a href=# id="prev">Prev</a> 
    <a href=# id="next">Next</a></span>
</div>
      </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add text-align center to the container div:

```
div.center {text-align:center;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dw25LLzc/